# Short story where man was mauled by dogs in dream

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I remember reading this story in an old High School literature textbook years ago (2009-2010 timeframe), but the story itself is probably a lot older. The entire story is framed in a series of letters and reports between police officials.

Basically this guy was arrested for possessing amphetamines, and he explained to the officers that he kept on having nightmares where he was captured by a mysterious group of people and they keep on trying to interrogate him. He got really scared when marks from the torture began to show up on his body after he woke up and began trying desperately to avoid sleep.

Eventually, the group in his dreams starts bringing out dogs to maul him, and he woke up barely before the dogs do reach him. He starts to go from coffee to amphetamines to avoid sleep, because he was sure that the dogs will get him when he falls asleep the next time. The police didn't believe him, and he falls asleep. He was eventually found dead in his sealed cell, with wounds consistent with an animal attack, and clutching to a handful of dog fur.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was this?  "Years ago" isn't very precise.

Comment: @DavidW It was 2009-2010 if I recall correctly. But probably much older.

Comment: Sounds almost like an homage to "The Howling Tower" by Fritz Leiber.

Comment: There's some Reddit posts asking about the same story, with some more details. There's a pit (https://old.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/fykdiw/tomt_story_guy_dreams_about_being_dropped_in_a/), at the end the doctor/therapist begins to hear the dogs as well (https://old.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/rp1hl/tomt_short_story_about_patient_who_tells_his/), and one person remembers the quote "if I could just get those damn dogs to stop barking" (https://old.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/vgbh46/tomt_short_story_about_a_man_who_stops_sleeping/)